# groupBy Clause Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

```
select n.l_id, n.fromorto, DATE(dtime),avg(mean_speed) as ms_sat_t
from newdataa n
inner join majhwys as m
on n.l_id = m.link_id
where n.day_number=6 and n.fromorto='T'
group by n.fromorto,CAST(dtime as DATE),n.l_id
order by n.l_id
```

There can be four combinations here on the where clause, day number 6/7, and fromorto - F/T. I am having to write 4 separate queries, is there a way i can write one query with 4 columns ( ms_sat_f, ms_sat_t, ms_sun_f, ms_sun_t). I am not really sure of writing subqueries. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it.

Comment: Result Columns -  l_id, ms_saturday_from, ms_saturday_to, ms_sunday_from, ms_sunday_to. ms represents mean speeds. dtime is a timestamp ( and data is grouped hourly ) . My result has to group it on day basis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation with the `filter` clause:

```
select n.l_id, n.fromorto, DATE(dtime),
       avg(mean_speed) filter (where n.day_number = 6 and n.fromorto = 'T') as ms_sat_t,
       avg(mean_speed) filter (where n.day_number = 6 and n.fromorto = 'F') as ms_sat_f,
       avg(mean_speed) filter (where n.day_number = 7 and n.fromorto = 'T') as ms_sun_t,
       avg(mean_speed) filter (where n.day_number = 7 and n.fromorto = 'F') as ms_sun_f
from newdataa n inner join
     majhwys m
     on n.l_id = m.link_id
group by n.fromorto, CAST(dtime as DATE), n.l_id
order by n.l_id;
```

In old versions of Postgres, you implement this using conditional aggregation:

```
avg(case when n.day_number = 6 and n.fromorto = 'T' then mean_speed end) as ms_sat_t,
```